# Does golang's go fmt not format brackets?

Tags: go

So I've been trying to use golang again and I remembered go has a formatting tool to clean up your source. So When I run `go fmt` on my project the following error gets spit out:

`expected declaration, found '{'`

I was expecting go fmt to fix my brackets to respect go's syntax requirements, but it just spits out an error. Is this intended functionality or is it supposed to actually put the bracket on the correct line (same line as the function declaration)?

Basic code in question that I was expecting to be properly formatted:

```
package main

func main()
{
    println("Learning go again")
}
```

Comment: fmt is supposed to format your code nicely, not to fix your syntax mistakes.

Comment: @tkausl can you respond as an answer not a comment so I can select it an answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go has some very strong opinions about what a valid code is.
This is one of the cases. Unlike many other C-family languages that allow putting curly bracket of function body declaration on the same line or on the next line (or even ten lines after, if you fancy), Go compiler allows it to be put only on the same line.

Another example is the else statement. Where in other languages

```
if {
}
else {
}
```

May be valid or even preferred, in Go only compiling else statement is of the form

```
if {
} else {
}
```

The `go fmt` will fix empty or missing spaces though:

```
func main()             {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

func main(){
   fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Will both become

```
func main() {
   fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Comment: It'll also allow stuff to sit on a single line, e.g. `func main() { fmt.Println() }` or `if err != nil { return err } else { fmt.Println("all okay") }`

Comment: Aaarg. Nothing like that mentioned in the introductory tutorials that I saw.